# How json array pages id dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

my json:

```
{
  "result": {
    "name": "json1",
      "pages": [{
          "zones": [{
              "title": "title1"
           },
           {
              "title": "title2"
           }],
           "id": 4
       },
       {
          "zones": [{
            "title": "title3"
          },
          {
            "title": "title4"
          }],
          "id": 12
       }],
       "creatorUserName": "admin",
       "id": 2
    }
}
```

how can I build an algorithm in dart flutter so I can get all pages title against Ids?

if (id = 12) zones print -> Text(title3), Text(title4),

---

else if empty zones print -> Text(title1), Text(title2), zones -> Text(title3), Text(title4),

my example code:

```
List post = snapshot.data["result"]["pages"];
List post = pagesArray; 
children: post.map((post) => Container(
                      child: Center(child: Text(post.title]),) 
                  )).toList(),
```

Comment: What is pagesArray?

Comment: accidentally added pagesArray deleted

Comment: Do you want to show it on some list? or just want algo to print these titles?

Comment: yes list and code :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like this:

```
void initState() {
  result = getResponse();
}

Widget getTextWidgets(var array)
{
  List<Widget> list = new List<Widget>();
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
      list.add(new Text(array[i]["title"], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)));
  }
  return new Row(children: list);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return MaterialApp(
    home:  Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Sample',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: result.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            if(result[index]["id"] == 4){
              getTextWidgets(result[index]["zones"]);
            }
            else if(result[index]["id"] == 12){
              getTextWidgets(result[index]["zones"]);
            }
          },
        ),
      ))
  );
}

getResponse() {

  var response = '{ "result": { "name": "json1", "pages": [{ "zones": [{ "title": "title1" }, { "title": "title2" }], "id": 4 }, { "zones": [{"title": "title3"}, {"title": "title4"}], "id": 12 }], "creatorUserName": "admin", "id": 2 }}';

  print('Respone ${response}');
  var value = json.decode(response);
  var pages = value["result"]["pages"];
  return pages;    
}
```